# How to get the same view each time when the tab is selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar based iphone application ,inwhich each tab is itself a navigation controller .So in each tab views there is subviews, which I am pushing in to the self.navigation controller.

**The problem is** when I push one view and then select anther tab and then to comeback I select the same tab ,then it will be showing that pushed view. Not the view that I am  wanted come.

Can anybody help me to achieve the rootview everytime the tab is selected?anybody has the idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for the UINavigationControllers to save their stacks of View Controllers and show the top most one each time you switch IUTabBarController tabs.  So, are you saying that you want each UINavigationController to release the stack each time the tab bar switches away from them?  If so, then look at the UITabBarControllerDelegate documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932

Here you have methods which will tell you when tabs are switched:

```
 – tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
 – tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

I'm assuming you know how delegate protocols work.

Then take a look at the documentation for UINavigationController, which has methods for 'popping' View Controllers off the stack:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934

This will pop to the top ('root') View Controller:

```
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

A word of caution - in general users expect UITabBarController tabs to retain the same view as when they last switched to it.

Oh and also, what you're talking about is the default behavior when a tabbar tab is tapped twice (ie. when it is tapped when that tabbar tab is already selected).

Comment: +1 for the clarification and detail of the answer. Awesome :)

Comment: good caution ,but when i am loading the tabbar i am in a view.on the button click of it i am adding the second view.so my part is right ?is it?and also can u help me in how i can do the poptorootviewcontrooler code in the didselect method?

Comment: I was added like this in to the didselect method  [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];but it is not working?

Comment: Check the didselect method is actually being called (with an NSLog() or debugger breakpoint).  Then check that viewController.navigationController is not nil. If it's still not working, we'd need more information.